# How to count Chatter posts in SOQL?

Tags: apex, soql, chatter, feeditem

Is there a way to count chatter posts for a specific record?
I tried simple query:

```
SELECT COUNT()
FROM FeedItem
WHERE Type = 'TextPost'
```

But this doesn't work in Apex since it throws an error `Implementation restriction: Aggregate queries are not allowed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately The [FeedItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) object doesn’t support aggregate functions in queries.
Other way of doing above would be querrying for FeedItems into a collection and checking the size in apex. Make sure to add any appropriate filters to the query to narrow down the results

```
List<FeedItem> fiLst = new List<FeedItem>();
fiLst = [SELECT Id FROM FeedItem WHERE Type = 'TextPost'];
system.debug("FeedItem Count:"+ fiLst.size());
```

In the meanwhile you can upvote for the idea [Aggregate Query on FeedItem](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000C2DwAAK)